# kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to parse the broker info from zookeeper from EC2 to elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-schema-registry

I have aws MSK set up and i am trying to sink records from MSK to elastic  search.
I am able to push data into MSK into json format .
I want to sink to elastic search .
I am able to do all set up correctly .
This is what i have done  on EC2 instance

```
wget /usr/local http://packages.confluent.io/archive/3.1/confluent-oss-3.1.2-2.11.tar.gz -P ~/Downloads/
tar -zxvf ~/Downloads/confluent-oss-3.1.2-2.11.tar.gz -C ~/Downloads/
sudo mv ~/Downloads/confluent-3.1.2 /usr/local/confluent

/usr/local/confluent/etc/kafka-connect-elasticsearch
```

After that i have modified kafka-connect-elasticsearch and set my elastic search url

```
name=elasticsearch-sink
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector
tasks.max=1
topics=AWSKafkaTutorialTopic
key.ignore=true
connection.url=https://search-abcdefg-risdfgdfgk-es-ex675zav7k6mmmqodfgdxxipg5cfsi.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com
type.name=kafka-connect
```

The producer sends message like below fomrat

```
{
        "data": {
                "RequestID":    517082653,
                "ContentTypeID":        9,
                "OrgID":        16145,
                "UserID":       4,
                "PromotionStartDateTime":       "2019-12-14T16:06:21Z",
                "PromotionEndDateTime": "2019-12-14T16:16:04Z",
                "SystemStartDatetime":  "2019-12-14T16:17:45.507000000Z"
        },
        "metadata":     {
                "timestamp":    "2019-12-29T10:37:31.502042Z",
                "record-type":  "data",
                "operation":    "insert",
                "partition-key-type":   "schema-table",
                "schema-name":  "dbo",
                "table-name":   "TRFSDIQueue"
        }
}
```

I am little confused in how will the kafka connect start here ?
if yes how can i start that ?

I also have started schema registry like below which gave me error.

```
/usr/local/confluent/bin/schema-registry-start /usr/local/confluent/etc/schema-registry/schema-registry.properties
```

When i do that i get below error

```
[2019-12-29 13:49:17,861] ERROR Server died unexpectedly:  (io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryMain:51)
kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to parse the broker info from zookeeper: {"listener_security_protocol_map":{"CLIENT":"PLAINTEXT","CLIENT_SECURE":"SSL","REPLICATION":"PLAINTEXT","REPLICATION_SECURE":"SSL"},"endpoints":["CLIENT:/
```

Please help .

As suggested in answer i upgraded the kafka connect version but then i started getting below error

```
 ERROR Error starting the schema registry (io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryRestApplication:63)
io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.exceptions.SchemaRegistryInitializationException: Error initializing kafka store while initializing schema registry
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaSchemaRegistry.init(KafkaSchemaRegistry.java:210)
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryRestApplication.initSchemaRegistry(SchemaRegistryRestApplication.java:61)
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryRestApplication.setupResources(SchemaRegistryRestApplication.java:72)
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryRestApplication.setupResources(SchemaRegistryRestApplication.java:39)
        at io.confluent.rest.Application.createServer(Application.java:201)
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryMain.main(SchemaRegistryMain.java:41)
Caused by: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.exceptions.StoreInitializationException: Timed out trying to create or validate schema topic configuration
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaStore.createOrVerifySchemaTopic(KafkaStore.java:168)
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaStore.init(KafkaStore.java:111)
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaSchemaRegistry.init(KafkaSchemaRegistry.java:208)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl$SingleWaiter.await(KafkaFutureImpl.java:108)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.get(KafkaFutureImpl.java:274)
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaStore.createOrVerifySchemaTopic(KafkaStore.java:161)
        ... 7 more
```

Comment: You might need to manually create the `_schemas` topic or there's logs above that error saying why it's timing out

Comment: @cricket_007 i will just try out 5.2 kafka connect version .I tried with 5.1 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, Confluent Platform 3.1.2 is fairly old. I suggest you get the version that aligns with the Kafka version

You start Kafka Connect using the appropriate `connect-*` scripts and properties located under bin and etc/kafka folders

For example,

```
/usr/local/confluent/bin/connect-standalone \
  /usr/local/confluent/etc/kafka/kafka-connect-standalone.properties \ 
  /usr/local/confluent/etc/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/quickstart.properties
```

If that works, you can move onto using connect-distributed command instead

Regarding Schema Registry, you can search its Github issues for multiple people trying to get MSK to work, but the root issue is related to MSK not exposing a PLAINTEXT listener and the Schema Registry not supporting named listeners. (This may have changed since versions 5.x)

---

You could also try using Connect and Schema Registry containers in ECS / EKS rather than extracting in an EC2 machine

Comment: You are right .I upgraded the version 5 and i think that error is gone ,But i started getting different error like  `ERROR Error starting the schema registry (io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryRestApplication:63)`

Comment: Since your data is JSON for now, I suggest skipping the Schema Registry if you only really care about the Elasticsearch connector. You can open a separate post about your Schema Registry issues

Comment: But how can i skip Schema registry ? That was also my question if my data is JSON do i need Schema registry ?

Comment: Kafka Connect with json converter does not require Schema Registry. The `schemas.enable` property means something different. Plus, Schema Registry only stores Avro schemas anyway

Comment: Sorry i did not get our pint ..So after kafka-connect-elasticsearch what should i do ?Do i have start something ? I am new to kafka so may be asking silly questions apology in advance .

Comment: You need to start Kafka Connect, and that's it https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connect_running

Comment: i got more Confused now .so till now whatever i have done is of no use .Will this command `/usr/local/confluent/bin/schema-registry-start /usr/local/confluent/etc/schema-registry/schema-registry.properties` not start that ?

Comment: Again, seems like you don't need Schema Registry. You're not using Avro. You instead want `/usr/local/confluent/bin/connect-standalone /usr/local/confluent/etc/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/quickstart.properties`

Comment: So i am not getting any message but when i ran above command i get this `INFO Usage: ConnectStandalone worker.properties connector1.properties [connector2.properties ...] (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:62)
` Does this mean my connector is running ?

Comment: No, I forgot to put the correct arguments. I updated my answer. And still, the documentation shows how the commands work