# Failed to find any class that implements Connector and which name matches io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, aws-msk

I have MSK running on aws and i am able to send records in and out from MSK .
I just wanted to use Kafka connect so that records coming into MSK will go to Elastic Search .
I have done below things but i am not sure if my connector is working properly or not ,Because i can not see records into Elastic Search 
This is the records that i am sending

```
{
        "data": {
                "RequestID":    517082653,
                "ContentTypeID":        9,
                "OrgID":        16145,
                "UserID":       4,
                "PromotionStartDateTime":       "2019-12-14T16:06:21Z",
                "PromotionEndDateTime": "2019-12-14T16:16:04Z",
                "SystemStartDatetime":  "2019-12-14T16:17:45.507000000Z"
        },
        "metadata":     {
                "timestamp":    "2019-12-29T10:37:31.502042Z",
                "record-type":  "data",
                "operation":    "insert",
                "partition-key-type":   "schema-table",
                "schema-name":  "dbo",
                "table-name":   "TRFSDIQueue"
        }
}
```

I have installed Kafka connect like this

```
wget /usr/local http://packages.confluent.io/archive/5.2/confluent-5.2.0-2.11.tar.gz -P ~/Downloads/

tar -zxvf ~/Downloads/confluent-5.2.0-2.11.tar.gz -C ~/Downloads/
sudo mv ~/Downloads/confluent-5.2.0 /usr/local/confluent

vim /usr/local/confluent/etc/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/quickstart-elasticsearch.properties
```

and change url and topic name

After that i have just started kafka connect like below

```
/usr/local/confluent/bin/connect-standalone /usr/local/confluent/etc/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/quickstart-elasticsearch.properties
```

This gave me output `INFO Usage: ConnectStandalone worker.properties connector1.properties [connector2.properties ...] (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:62)`

So no where i have mentioned my Broker details ad zookeper details then i how will it connect to MSK .

Please help me understand this .What am i missing .
I do not schema transformation so i am not modifying `schema-registry.properties` .

When i tried using below command i got below error

```
/usr/local/confluent/bin/connect-standalone /home/ec2-user/kafka_2.12-2.2.1/config/connect-standalone.properties /usr/local/confluent/etc/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/quickstart-elasticsearch.properties


[2019-12-30 03:19:30,149] ERROR Failed to create job for /usr/local/confluent/etc/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/quickstart-elasticsearch.properties (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:108)
[2019-12-30 03:19:30,149] ERROR Stopping after connector error (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:119)
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Failed to find any class that implements Connector and which name matches io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector, available connectors are: PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSinkConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSinkConnector', version='2.2.0-cp1', encodedVersion=2.2.0-cp1, type=sink, typeName='sink', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSourceConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSourceConnector', version='2.2.0-cp1', encodedVersion=2.2.0-cp1, type=source, typeName='source', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockConnector', version='2.2.0-cp1', encodedVersion=2.2.0-cp1, type=connector, typeName='connector', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSinkConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSinkConnector', version='2.2.0-cp1', encodedVersion=2.2.0-cp1, type=sink, typeName='sink', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSourceConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSourceConnector', version='2.2.0-cp1', encodedVersion=2.2.0-cp1, type=source, typeName='source', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.SchemaSourceConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.SchemaSourceConnector', version='2.2.0-cp1', encodedVersion=2.2.0-cp1, type=source, typeName='source', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSinkConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSinkConnector', version='2.2.0-cp1', encodedVersion=2.2.0-cp1, type=source, typeName='source', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSourceConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSourceConnector', version='2.2.0-cp1', encodedVersion=2.2.0-cp1, type=source, typeName='source', location='classpath'}
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConvertingFutureCallback.result(ConvertingFutureCallback.java:79)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConvertingFutureCallback.get(ConvertingFutureCallback.java:66)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone.main(ConnectStandalone.java:116)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Failed to find any class that implements Connector and which name matches io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector, available connectors are: PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSinkConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSinkConnector', version='2.2.0-cp1', encodedVersion=2.2.0-cp1, type=sink, typeName='sink', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSourceConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSourceConnector', version='2.2.0-cp1', encodedVersion=2.2.0-cp1, type=source, typeName='source', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockConnector', version='2.2.0-cp1', encodedVersion=2.2.0-cp1, type=connector, typeName='connector', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSinkConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSinkConnector', version='2.2.0-cp1', encodedVersion=2.2.0-cp1, type=sink, typeName='sink', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSourceConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSourceConnector', version='2.2.0-cp1', encodedVersion=2.2.0-cp1, type=source, typeName='source', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.SchemaSourceConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.SchemaSourceConnector', version='2.2.0-cp1', encodedVersion=2.2.0-cp1, type=source, typeName='source', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSinkConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSinkConnector', version='2.2.0-cp1', encodedVersion=2.2.0-cp1, type=source, typeName='source', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSourceConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSourceConnector', version='2.2.0-cp1', encodedVersion=2.2.0-cp1, type=source, typeName='source', location='classpath'}
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.newConnector(Plugins.java:175)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractHerder.getConnector(AbstractHerder.java:382)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractHerder.validateConnectorConfig(AbstractHerder.java:261)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.standalone.StandaloneHerder.putConnectorConfig(StandaloneHerder.java:188)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone.main(ConnectStandalone.java:113)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to parse the broker info from zookeeper from EC2 to elastic search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59518856/kafka-common-kafkaexception-failed-to-parse-the-broker-info-from-zookeeper-from)

Comment: I showed you the correct command in that answer.

Comment: You need to add the plugins path in your `connect-*.properties` file shown in example at the end of the file.

Answer (score 1):

You put your bootstrap servers and Connect related properties in the etc/kafka/connect-standalone.properties file

To load the Connector, you must use `plugin.path` as discussed here

https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/managing/community.html

You can also instead download Confluent Hub CLI to setup any Apache Kafka Connector available there (you don't require Confluent Platform, thus you can ignore Schema Registry)

https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/managing/confluent-hub/client.html

Or as answered before, use the Confluent Kafka Connect docker images, which have Elasticsearch connector pre-loaded

Plus, I would suggest not using tarballs and instead use APT/YUM to get Confluent packages installed

https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/installing_cp/index.html